# check if fields of a sqlserver table are empty/full in a computed field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-trigger, computed-field

i need to add a computed field in a sqlserver table that shows me if the other fields of the table are empty or full (all, some of them, none)

the field should contain:

```
0=all the fields are empty(null)
1=almost one field has been filled
2=all fields contains something
```

What is the most efficent way to achieve it?

Comment: This seems like a better choice for a view; you could only achieve this with a scalar function, and that's going to kill performance. Also you've tagged SQL Server 2005; that's been out of support for a few years now, are you really still using it? I'd suggest it's past time to upgrade now, so you should be doing so at the soonest opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to to do this is summing up all the null columns using `case ...when` statements and then comparing that to the total number of columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo] (
[Col1] int NULL,
[Col2] int NULL,
[Col3] int NULL,
[ColumnDensity] AS CASE 
       CASE WHEN [Col1] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
       CASE WHEN [Col2] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
       CASE WHEN [Col3] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
    WHEN 0 /* No columns are NOT NULL */ THEN 0 
    WHEN 3 /* All 3 columns are NOT NULL */ THEN 2 
    ELSE /* Some columns are NULL and some are NOT NULL*/ 1 END
)
```